# Google Cloud Logging + google-fluentd Dropping Messages

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, fluentd

I have a rather small (1-2 node) kubernetes cluster running in GKE with ±40 Pods running. The problem at hand is that it's not logging to the GCE Console properly. I see lots of messages from the fluentd container(s) in the following format:

```
$ kubectl logs fluentd-cloud-logging-gke-xxxxxxxx-node-xxxx

2016-02-02 23:30:09 +0000 [warn]: Dropping 10 log message(s) error_class="Google::APIClient::ClientError" error="Project has not enabled the API. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the 'logging' API for your project."
2016-02-02 23:30:09 +0000 [warn]: Dropping 1 log message(s) error_class="Google::APIClient::ClientError" error="Project has not enabled the API. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the 'logging' API for your project."
2016-02-02 23:30:09 +0000 [warn]: Dropping 3 log message(s) error_class="Google::APIClient::ClientError" error="Project has not enabled the API. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the 'logging' API for your project."
2016-02-02 23:30:09 +0000 [warn]: Dropping 41 log message(s) error_class="Google::APIClient::ClientError" error="Project has not enabled the API. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the 'logging' API for your project."
2016-02-02 23:30:09 +0000 [warn]: Dropping 5 log message(s) error_class="Google::APIClient::ClientError" error="Project has not enabled the API. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the 'logging' API for your project."
```

...and so on. I'm seeing ~5 of these messages per second, so I know things are producing logs. However, in the compute engine console I see something like the following:

[image: compute engine console logging page snapshot with some portions redacted]

So somewhere in between I'm obviously loosing lots of messages. Strange though, that I'm not loosing *all* these messages!

The cluster is configured with Logging.write and Monitoring.all privileges as suggested in GH issue [#15727](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15727)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely confusing that some of the logs are showing up. Given that error message, I'd expect none of your logs to be showing up in the viewer, since it sounds like the logging API hasn't been enabled for your project yet.

You can do so from the Developers Console, [here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/logging/overview). Try going there, clicking the `Enable API` button, and seeing whether the errors keep coming.

Comment: When I first loaded the console I saw {{apiCtrl.api.name}} where the button should have been, but after a cache-busting refresh, the button appeared. Clicking it did the trick, thanks Alex!